# Append Divs to Container and keeping them in a horizontal line

Tags: css, html

I have a container DIV that is resizable. I allow the user to add DIV elements to it, to create some sort of a playlist. When the container DIV is not large enough for a content DIV to be appended, I want the content DIV to just get cut off at the end of the container DIV. Unfortunately it always gets appended underneath other content elements. I tried `overflow:hidden;` for the container element, but that didn't have any effect...

Comment: Maybe if you could paste some code of yours here so we can help you? Or on http://jsfiddle.net/ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: give the container div a set height too or you need an inner container that will expand by the new divs width as you add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
overflow:hidden;
```

is a good choice, but you need an inner container where contents can be added horizontally, an inner container larger than the visible outer one.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kREqG/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `white-space:nowrap` to your parent div. When you add children they will be appended without breaking to the next line - even if the parent container is not as wide as the width of the children divs.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/XqSJG/14/)**